# VW elements overflowing

Tags: html, css

Why 2 divs are overflowing each other?
I have equally divided two divs with viewport width.
Insted of 50% width  if I am giving 49% then code is working fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
        }
        .fity{
            width: 50vw;
            height: 100vh;
            float: left;        

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="fity" style="background:red;"></div>
<div class="fity" style="background:blue;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you change `vw` to `%` still with the same problem?

Comment: Percentages workin fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the vertical scroll bar.

[**MDN Information**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length)

> Viewport-percentage lengths defined a length relatively to the size of
>   viewport, that is the visible portion of the document. Only
>   Gecko-based browsers are updating the viewport values dynamically,
>   when the size of the viewport is modified (by modifying the size of
>   the window on a desktop computer or by turning the device on a phone
>   or a tablet).
>
> In conjunction with overflow:auto, **space taken by eventual scrollbars
>   is not substracted from the viewport**, whereas in the case of
>   overflow:scroll, it is. [*My Emphasis*]

If you add `overflow:hidden` to the body it gets fixed. -

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3b5gc8k3/1/)

Comment: My page is very lenghty. cannot able to scrolling after adding overflow hidden